# SQL select statement equivalent for query on plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I am trying to figure out the best approach for queries on a plist. Thus, attempting at making an sql equivalent to "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somecol = someval AND someothercol = someotherval AND ".... so on and soforth ... using a plist as the sql table equivalent. Coming from Ruby and mysql, this just seems like a lot of code for one simply query. The results come back as expected (at least at first run they did, I have not tested this rigorously) with no errors.

So here is the question: Is there some simple method hiding in the docs somewhere that would make this less clunky?
and if not what is a better approach?

EPFramework.m

```
// LOAD PLIST AND FILTER MULTIPLE TIMES
-(NSMutableArray *)loadPlistAndFilterMultipleTimes:(NSString *)plist ArrayOfKeys:(NSArray *)arrayOfKeys ArrayOfKeyValues:(NSArray *)arrayOfKeyValues
{

// set the array counts
int arrayOfKeysCount = [arrayOfKeys count];
int arrayOfKeyValuesCount = [arrayOfKeyValues count];

// initialize the array to return
NSMutableArray *arrayFilteredResults = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];

// qualify the search
if(arrayOfKeysCount == arrayOfKeyValuesCount && arrayOfKeysCount > 0 && arrayOfKeyValuesCount > 0)
{

    // get the plist
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", plist];
    NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fullFileName];

    // put the plist records into an array
    NSArray *arrayOfDictionaryItemsInPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // load our dynamic array for mutability throughout the loops
    NSMutableArray *arrayFiltered = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayOfDictionaryItemsInPlist] retain];

    // build an array of the final results to return
    for(int i=0; i < arrayOfKeysCount; i ++)
    {

        // initialize this loops search criteria
        NSString *key = [arrayOfKeys objectAtIndex:i];
        id value = [arrayOfKeyValues objectAtIndex:i];

        // set the filter
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, value];

        // filter the result
        arrayFilteredResults = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[arrayFiltered filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]] retain];

    } 
} else {
    NSLog(@"arrOfKeys count does not match arrayOfKeyValues count"); // the search did not qualify
}


// return the results
return arrayFilteredResults;    

// release the allocated memory
[arrayFilteredResults release];     

}
```

IndexController.m

```
NSArray *arrayOfKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSString stringWithString:@"recordset"],
                         [NSString stringWithString:@"ep_object_attribute_id"], 
                         nil];

NSArray *arrayOfKeyValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSString stringWithString:@"1778587279"], 
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:133], 
                             nil];

NSMutableArray *arrayOfResult = [epFrameWork loadPlistAndFilterMultipleTimes:@"FormEntries" ArrayOfKeys:arrayOfKeys ArrayOfKeyValues:arrayOfKeyValues];
NSLog(@"arrayOfResult: %@", arrayOfResult);
```

Comment: It seems like you are writing more code and getting worst performance than just going with CoreData or sqlite.  When you're using a series of plists to simulate tables in a database, why not just use a database or CoreData?

Comment: In a nutshell, I only have 1 month to get my project out the door. I've only been doing objective-c for about a month or so. From everything I have researched and code samples I have looked at, it seemed to me that the learning curve for all other alternatives to plists was too steep for the timeframe I have. What would you recommended given my situation? From your point of view, are plists for data storage just as complex as the database or core data approach? Perhaps I'm rather turned in the wrong direction about the whole data storage topic.

Comment: My project really is simple enough I didn't anticipate the need for learning core data, at least not this month. From all my calculations and the specs for the project, I had just determined that plists would well suffice.

Comment: Don't use Core Data then, just use SQLite. But honestly you can pick up either in less than a day. This seems like sado-masochism at its best.

Comment: Well now that's some food for thought. Thanks for the pointers, which was what I was asking for :)

Comment: BTW, check out fmdb in github.  I was using it in an hour. hth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link for fmdb.  Should be quick to pick it up, be faster and you get a real database instead of simulating one with plists :)

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Hope that helps